# Help with mod_rewite rule

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess, regex

I have a rule that will get the extension of every file from the url. I need to match all jpg, gif, png and bmp files. This is for a watermark application. Currently, it only matches jpg and Jpg. Can someone help me match all four extensions?

Here is what I currently have so far.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.[jJgG].*)$ /test.php?i=$1
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look to [this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html)
You will learn that you can use [NC] to do a case insensitive match.
Your .* at the end seems strange if you only want to match url ending with jpg, etc..
So what you want is probably this:

```
RewriteRule ^/(.*\.(jpg|gif|png|bmp))$ /test.php?i=$1 [NC]
```

Note that in the [doc](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) there is almost the same RewriteRule.
You may want to use [NC,P] to make the rewrite rule to be processed internaly rather than sending a redirect message to the broswer.